# Sql Server ( Windows authentication ) in Docker Compose For Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, docker-compose

I have Asp.net Project And I Use Docker Compose
I want To Connect Sql With **Windows Authentication**
But I Can't
Can You Help Me ?
appsetting :

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings":{
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=*******;Database=******;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Docker-Compose :

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  connectsqltodocker:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}connectsqltodocker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ConnectSqlToDocker/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
       - OKKouroshCard  
  OKKouroshCard:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
```

[image: appsetting]

[image: solution]

[image: docker-Compose]

Comment: Please post code as code and not screenshots/images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use windows authentication with SQL server docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398423/how-to-use-windows-authentication-with-sql-server-docker-container)

Comment: Active Directory/Kerberos authentication to an SQL Server instance in a Docker for Linux container is an advanced topic. You'll need to start with [Tutorial: Configure Active Directory authentication with SQL Server on Linux containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-containers-ad-auth-adutil-tutorial).

Comment: No ,No one could answer @1SaeedSalehi

Comment: Thank ... but This is not my answer @AlwaysLearning